# how to scale an image with gimp and save the actual scale and all the white space

Tags: export, scale, gimp

there are a ton of scaling instructions for GIMP but all of them tell you to scale and save easy peasy. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.
This is what my save or export generates:
[image]

How can I simply export a selection? Shouldn't the GIMP instructions include this detail? Sorry for ranting.

Comment: So to help others, the trick is to copy and: "edit>paste as>image"

Answer (score 1):

In Gimp (and some other popular image editors) the image you work on is actually made of separate images (a.ka.a layers) held together on a "canvas". The "canvas" gives the size of the final image.

There are three different ways to scale things and you have to use the right one:

- The Scale tool [image]: scales  the active layer by dragging corners. Doesn't change the size of the canvas. This is probably what you used.
- `Layer>Scale layer`: scales the active layer by providing explicit dimensions. Doesn't change the size of the canvas.
- `Image>Scale image`: scales the whole image contents **and the canvas**. This is probably what you should have used.

What happened to give you the image above is that you resized the layer using the Scale tool, so you got a tiny image in the corner of the canvas, which didn't change size. The uncovered part of the canvas was displayed as a checkerboard pattern. If you exported to a format that supports transparency such as PNG or GIF the image would have been transparent, but since you exported to JPG which doesn't support transparent images Gimp replaced the transparent part by the default background color.

Comment: Thank you for explaining so well!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is well explained on their website. https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMP_Quickies/

Comment: sorry but that is actually my point: it is NOT. if you follow their instructions you'll end up with my example result full of white space.